# How can we change erc20 tokens logo?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I have deployed my contract here https://etherscan.io/address/0x9b03d6b95bb730d1be29658f6b879ecf6c1c64a8

I would like to change its logo to my custom picture. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The picture is done manually by etherscan. You'll have to contact them at https://etherscan.io/contactus